# Is it possible to view AWS Lambda Layer logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to use this lambda layer https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-lambda-python but it fails because one of the variables is uninitialized. Looking at the code, there are log statements so I'd like to investigate them. Those lambda layer logs do not show up in my lambda function's logs though. How would I be able to see the logs from the lambda layer?

Comment: I think you need to set the `DD_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to `debug` according to the README in the project you linked.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I wasn't sure if layers just didn't log but that did the trick